# Prove $\alpha$ is well difined

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

I am working on this question,

> Define $\alpha$ : $\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ by $\alpha( \frac{a}{ b} ) = \frac{a + 3b}{ 2b }$, where a and b are integers and $b \neq 0$. Prove that α is well-defined.

**Proof:**

Let $m$, $n$ $\in \mathbb{Q}$ and there exist integers $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ such that 
$m=\frac{a}{b}$ with $b\neq 0$ and $n=\frac{c}{d}$ with $d\neq 0$.

assume $m=n$, we have  $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d} $. Since $\alpha (\frac{a}{b})=\frac{a + 3b}{ 2b }$, so $\alpha(\frac{c}{d})=\frac{c + 3d}{ 2d }$. Because $m=n$, so $\frac{a + 3b}{ 2b }=\frac{c + 3d}{ 2d }$. Therefore, $\alpha$ is well defined. $\square$

I think my proof miss some details need to show. Can anyone tell me what they are? OR give me a hit or suggestion to write a better proof.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that your proof is quite wrong.  All you have really done is to state that since $m=n$, we have $\alpha(m)=\alpha(n)$.  This is what is meant by $\alpha$ being well-defined, but you have not actually given any reasons.

Also, since $m=n$, there is really no point in having both $m$ and $n$.  In fact, I wouldn't bother having either.  What you need to prove is:

> if $\frac ab=\frac cd$, then $\frac{a+3b}{2b}=\frac{c+3d}{2d}$.

So, assume that
$$\frac ab=\frac cd\ ;$$
then
$$\frac12\frac ab+\frac32=\frac12\frac cd+\frac32\ ;$$
and simplifying this gives the result you need.

Answer (score 2):

***Hint:*** Let $m = \frac{a}{b}, b \neq 0.$ Then $\alpha(m) = \frac{a+3b}{2b}.$ Now suppose $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}, d \neq 0.$ Then $ad=bc \Rightarrow a = \frac{bc}{d}.$ Replacing $a$ in the expression of $\alpha(m),$ we get that $\alpha(\frac{a}{b})=\alpha(\frac{c}{d}).$

You can't start with $m=n.$ To show a map is well defined, you need to show that the map is not dependent on a particular representation of any elements. (Here $m=\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$ are two different representation of $m$ and we showed that it doesn't matter what representation we choose the image of $m$ will be the same.)